# ¿Se le puede cambiar el nombre a un entorno en conda?

Tags: conda

¿Se le puede cambiar el nombre a un entorno en conda? Por ejemplo tengo un entorno llamado py34 y quisiera cambiar el nombre a py3k, en vez de tener que crear un entorno nuevamente con este nombre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usé conda una vez y nunca intenté hacer algo asi, viendo en la [documentación](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#remove-an-environment) no veo nada parecido a editar el nombre de un entorno virtual.

Lo más cercano podría ser primero [clonar](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#clone-an-environment) el ambiente virtual y luego [eliminar](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#remove-an-environment) el antiguo:

```
$ conda create --name py3k --clone py34
$ conda remove --name py34 --all
```

---

Podría existir otra opción (no recomendada) que implica modificar algunas cosas en la carpeta `~/.conda`. Primero tendrías que editar el archivo `environments.txt` que usa conda para llevar el control de las URLs de los entornos virtuales:

```
$ cat ~/.conda/environments.txt 
/home/jdash/.conda/envs/py34
```

Modifícalo usando `nano` o tu editor favorito a:

```
/home/jdash/.conda/envs/py3k
```

Luego solo quedaría renombrar la carpeta de tu entorno virtual:

```
$ ls -l ~/.conda/envs/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 8 jdash jdash 4096 dic  9 21:29 py34
$ mv ~/.conda/envs/py34 ~/.conda/envs/py3k
```

Finalmente, activa tu entorno virtual:

```
$ source activate py3k
```

Answer (score 0):

En conda 23.11.0 hay una opción `conda rename -n nombre_ambiente nuevo_nombre`